# Page containing a frameset can I replace all the frames with a single page

Tags: html, frameset

My webpage consists of three frames, the bottom one contains a footer. But clicking a link on the footer just replaces the footer frame. I want to replace the whole page (essentially like a back button) can I do that ?

The footer link can go back to server, and I can use Javascript if that helps.

FWIW I know framesets have long been on their way out and I would like to not use them but there are some particular issues that mean I may have to keep them, it will certainly be a task to remove them. So at least for now can I solve my issue whilst continuing to use framesets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a link in a frameset you always need the frame, where the content has to be shown. To remove all frames use target _top in your link.

```
<a href="path/to/your/file.html" target="_top">Replace frameset</a>
```